# Upgraded my device from KitKat to Lollipop, is there a way to get the airplane mode back to the power options?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, 5.0-lollipop, power-options

I recently upgraded my phone's OS from KitKat to Lollipop, and noticed that when I press the power button for an extended time to open the power options, there is no longer a quick button to put the device into airplane mode, which was present in the KitKat version. The only way I can now put my phone to airplane mode is via the settings menu, which is not as fast and effective as it used to be. Does anyone know if it is possible to add the airplane mode function to the power options and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: you'll probably need root at least. does the notification bar toggles not have airplane mode included?

Comment: Yes, seems the notification bar has airplane mode included when swiped all the way down. That will be my new quick way to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way Google wanted the power menu to work in Android Lollipop. It's just terribly inconvenient for those who used Android before. But if you really need to bring back the feature and have a rooted phone, you can [try this method](http://nexus5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/bring-back-airplane-mode-audio-toggles-your-nexus-5s-power-menu-0159661/) which works on Nexus.

But you don't need to go to the settings to enable Airplane mode. From the top of the screen, just swipe down twice or drag down once using two fingers to reveal the Airplane mode toggle.

It's the quickest way to use the Airplane mode in Lollipop. Some apps in play store([Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en), [Toggle Airplane](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.toggleairplane&hl=en)) has shortcuts to enable Airplane mode but you need a rooted phone for that to work.

Comment: the swiping was new to me since just getting acquainted with the new Lollipoop, thanks for the help.